KinectV2 with ROS2 Humble
I'm trying to use KinectV2 with ROS2 Humble, in all the research I've done there's no further information than in WIP codes that didn't help me a lot. I need depth data and point cloud info for tracking humans or dynamic objects. Does anyone know where can I find a source code or could give me any advice of previous works? Please and thanks.

Have you tried kinect2_ros2 package?
I am using this package to run kinect v2 on ros2 humble。
Point cloud and depth images are captured correctly and working fine. However, in my case there was an error error: no matching functionwhen building, so I had to modify the line 209 of the　depth_registration_opencl.cpp。
cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));
⇩
cl::Program::Sources source;source.emplace_back(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length());

Could you be more specific about the modification? Please [edit] and update your answer.

your answer becomes useless when the link dies ... at least explain what package you are talking about
